# I need help breaking this query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
SELECT *
FROM(
Select P.FirstName, P.LastName, ST.Name, rank() over(partition by st.name order by sp.salesYTD desc) as ranking, SP.SalesYTD
FROM Sales.SalesTerritory ST INNER JOIN SALES.SalesPerson SP
ON SP.TerritoryID= SP.TerritoryID
INNER JOIN Person.Person P
ON SP.BusinessEntityID=P.BusinessEntityID
group by st.name, P.FirstName, P.LastName, sp.SalesYTD
) TEMP
WHERE ranking=1;
```

So the question that I have tonight,  I am trying to get the top sales person from each region but this is just showing the top sales person and putting them in every region. Is there a way to break this up so that I can get the top name for each region?

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to get the top sales person from each region

The issue is your ranking.  You would seem to want to partition by the region, which I think is `TerritoryID`:

```
rank() over (partition by st.TerritoryID order by sp.salesYTD desc)
```

In addition, I don't think you need aggregation.

Comment: So that puts the top sales person in every region? Which isnt correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.FirstName, p.LastName, st.Name,x.MaxSales from Sales.SalesPerson sp 
inner join 
(select TerritoryID,max(salesytd) as MaxSales
from SALES.SalesPerson group by TerritoryID) x on x.TerritoryID = sp.TerritoryID and 
sp.SalesYTD = x.MaxSales
inner join Sales.SalesTerritory ST  on st.TerritoryID = sp.TerritoryID
INNER JOIN Person.Person P ON SP.BusinessEntityID=P.BusinessEntityID
```

I should have just used max() I was trying to over complicate the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you try and simplify the query.

Can you re-post the query without all the aliases?

Also give a list of tables and columns used to avoid sim-interpation.